# Create multiple condition with BiPredicate and BiFunction java

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I try to create multiple condition with BiPredicate and BiFunction java. Maybe we can use some list or array for tackle this.
For example I have such code:

```
if (engine.evalTrue(F.GreaterEqual(min, F.CN1)) &&  engine.evalTrue(F.LessEqual(max, F.C1))) {
    result.set(i, F.List(F.ArcSin(min), F.ArcSin(max)));
} else {
    return F.NIL;
}
```

I can replace with:

```
(min, max) -> engine.evalTrue(F.GreaterEqual(min, F.CN1)) && engine.evalTrue(F.LessEqual(max, F.C1)), //
                (min, max) -> F.List(F.ArcSin(min), F.ArcSin(max)));
```

But if I have more conditions, for example:

```
if (engine.evalTrue(F.GreaterEqual(min, F.C0)) && //
        engine.evalTrue(F.GreaterEqual(max, F.C0))) {
    result.append(F.List(F.Csch(max), F.Csch(min)));
} else if (engine.evalTrue(F.Less(min, F.C0)) && //
        engine.evalTrue(F.GreaterEqual(max, F.C0))) {
    result.append(F.List(F.CNInfinity, F.Csch(min)));
    result.append(F.List(F.Csch(max), F.CInfinity));
} else if (engine.evalTrue(F.Less(min, F.C0)) && //
        engine.evalTrue(F.Less(max, F.C0))) {
    result.append(F.List(F.Csch(min), F.Csch(max)));
} else {
    return F.NIL;
}
```

How can I apply here BiPredicate and BiFunction java?

Comment: what are BIPredicate and BiFunction?

Comment: BiFunction: https://mkyong.com/java8/java-8-bifunction-examples/

Comment: Package java.util.function: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html
Interface BiPredicate: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiPredicate.html